# Собственный атрибут

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core, атрибуты

Подскажите как это реализуется, ни разу такого не делал.
Мне надо, перед методом проверять, имеет ли роль пользователя, разрешения на использования метода. Например, я хочу перед методом ActionIndex написать [Permission(User = user, Permission = "read")], а внутри взять и проверить, ну например:

```
if (!User.HasPerm(Permission))
    RedirectToAction("AccesDenied");
```

Как то так.

Comment: [раз](https://habr.com/ru/post/322566/), [два](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36447358/312041)?

Comment: @tym32167 Посмотрите пожалуйста мой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Сделал вот так. Возможно не правильно, но работает.

```
public class PermissionAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public PermissionAttribute(string[] permissionCodes) : base(typeof(PermissionFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { permissionCodes };
    }
}

public class PermissionFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private ApplicationContext _context;

    readonly string[] _permissionCodes;

    public PermissionFilter(string[] permissionCodes, ApplicationContext context)
    {
        _permissionCodes = permissionCodes;
        _context = context;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var userId = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        var userRolesId = _context.UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == userId).Select(ur => ur.RoleId).ToList();
        var permissionCodes = _context.PermissionsRoles.Where(pr => userRolesId.Contains(pr.RoleId)).Select(pr => pr.Permission.Code).ToArray();

        bool hasPermission = false;

        foreach (var permissionCode in _permissionCodes)
        {
            if (permissionCodes.Contains(permissionCode))
            {
                hasPermission = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hasPermission)
        {
           context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }

}
```

В контроллере:

```
[Permission(new string[] { "CreateUser" })]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_view + RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), _userManager.Users.ToList()); 
}
```

Теперь думаю как сделать проверку в разметке)

Answer (score 0):

Я переделал что бы можно было так же и во `view` проверять `permission`. Надеюсь помогу кому то еще кроме себя.
**Пример проверки в контроллере:**

```
[Permission(new string[] { "EditUser" })]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_view + RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), _userManager.Users.ToList()); 
}
```

**Пример во вью:**

```
@if (User.IsHasPermission(new string[] {"CreateUser"}))
{
<h2>Работает</h2>
}
```

**Реализация:**
Расширяющий класс:

```
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static bool IsHasPermission(this ClaimsPrincipal user, string [] PermissionCodes)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Startup.connectingString);

        using (ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
        {
            var userId = user.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            var userRolesId = context.UserRoles.Where(ur => ur.UserId == userId).Select(ur => ur.RoleId).ToList();
            var permissionCodes = context.PermissionsRoles.Where(pr => userRolesId.Contains(pr.RoleId)).Select(pr => pr.Permission.Code).ToArray();

            foreach (var permissionCode in PermissionCodes)
            {
                if (permissionCodes.Contains(permissionCode))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Атрибут:**

```
 public class PermissionAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public PermissionAttribute(string[] permissionCodes) : base(typeof(PermissionFilter))
        {
            Arguments = new object[] { permissionCodes };
        }
    }

    public class PermissionFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private ApplicationContext _context;

        readonly string[] _permissionCodes;

        public PermissionFilter(string[] permissionCodes, ApplicationContext context)
        {
            _permissionCodes = permissionCodes;
            _context = context;
        }

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (!context.HttpContext.User.IsHasPermission(_permissionCodes))
            {
               context.Result = new ForbidResult();
            }
        }

    }
```